# DateTime.ParseExact was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: vb.net, datetime, formatting

I'm trying to convert a `String` to a `Date` format using this code:

```
 Debug.Print(Trim(oTable.Cell(i + 1, 2).Range.Text.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")))
 Tabledate = DateTime.ParseExact((Trim(oTable.Cell(i + 1, 2).Range.Text.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, ""))), "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

the `Debug.Print` line gives me the result `30/12/15`, but the `DateTime.ParseExact` line always returns an error saying the string was not a valid DateTime format? Am I missing something?

Note: I have to remove trailing return carragies because the string is coming from a table in word, and for some reason pulls out a return on the end of the string

**UPDATE 1**

Resorting to desperate measures, I've included the following in my code:

```
For Each A As Char In oTable.Cell(i + 1, 2).Range.Text
    Debug.Print(A)
Next
```

This is printing the result:

```
3
0
/
1
2
/
1
5
(extra blank char)
(extra blank char)
```

I have no idea where or what these blank characters are, I've tried replacing `vbTab` with nothing too but it makes no difference. It might be worth noting that the String originally comes from a Table in word, could the fact its in a cell on a table have anything to do with what these blank characters are?

**UPDATE 2**

Changed the debug code to:

```
For Each A As Char In oTable.Cell(i + 1, 2).Range.Text
    Debug.Print(CInt(AscW(A)))
Next
```

Returned:

```
51
48
47
49
50
47
49
53
13
7
```

which I believe means 13 is a carriage return (even though it should have been trimmed out) and 7 is a "bell" (I have no idea what a bell is)

Comment: Updated Question, I wanted to leave it in there incase the `Trim` command or `Replace` is the reason for the error. The returned string is in the Question to be fair, its `30/12/15`

Comment: Cannot reproduce using a constant "30/12/15", so there is something not clear here. What is your real locale info?

Comment: @SilverShotBee: maybe there are other invisible characters like `VbTab` inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old VB function [`Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.trim(v=vs.110).aspx) removes only spaces from the beginning and the end. Use the .NET method [`String.Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx) instead which removes all kind of [whitespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) like also tab-characters.

```
Dim celltext =  oTable.Cell(i + 1, 2).Range.Text.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")
Tabledate = DateTime.ParseExact(celltext.Trim(), "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Note that you also could use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) if the input can contain invalid dates. Then no exception happens but the method returns `False`.

---

Since you have the carriage return(not at the end) and the bell(at the end) you might want to use this approach which should remove all unwanted characters:

```
Dim celltext = oTable.Cell(i + 1, 2).Range.Text.Trim()
Dim validChars = From c In celltext Where Char.IsDigit(c) OrElse Char.IsPunctuation(c)
celltext = New String(validChars.ToArray())
Tabledate = DateTime.ParseExact(celltext, "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

You need to add `Imports System.Linq` to the top of the code file.

Comment: Thanks, this is returning `False` so I guess there is an issue, please see the updated Question

Comment: @SilverShotBee: so you have tried `DateTime.ParseExact(celltext.Trim(), "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` but `celltext.Trim()` didn't remove the trailing spaces? Use `Debug.Print(CInt(A))` to see which kind of character it is.

Comment: @Steve, Updated again, interesting approach to get the character code! I'll remember that

Comment: Haha, sorry, it's been a long day!

Comment: @SilverShotBee: look at my new approach

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I'll have to save that approach for future use! (I didn't need `System.Linq` however)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the string produced is not in a correct pattern.
Please note that CultureInfo.InvariantCulture needs a certain datetime formatting to make it work.

```
CultureInfo c1 = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

Console.WriteLine( c1.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToString());
Console.WriteLine( c1.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern.ToString());
```

You will see the format needed to use are the following

```
MM/dd/yyyy
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy
```

The DateTime.ParseExact will throw a FormatException because standard short date pattern or long date pattern is not followed.