# Date Differences between Windows 10 and Windows 7

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I recently asked this question:
[DateTime.ParseExact was not recognized as a valid DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427521/datetime-parseexact-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime)

The question was answered and the approach worked great. This was until I tried running it on a windows 10 machine. I then get the error:

> String Not Recognized As Valid DateTime

By "String" I assume the debugger is referencing the `dd/MM/yy`. Does anyone have any idea why this may be? Here's the code if you don't want to trawl through the linked question:

```
Tabledate = DateTime.ParseExact("30/11/12", "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to [@Blackwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4424957/blackwood) for the comment about the actual computers time, I just changed window's 10 Short Date format to "dd/MM/yy" from "dd/MM/yyyy" and the code runs fine!

Now I don't know what format other people's computers may be in, so I suppose my next approach will be to research if I can obtain what format the current PC is in and then use that format as a variable

Comment: Assuming that `Tabledate` is declared as `DateTime`, that code runs on my Windows 10 computer without error. The value assigned to `Tabledate` is "11/30/2012 12:00:00 AM" (in the US culture that my computer defaults to).

Comment: *By "String" I assume the debugger is referencing the `dd/MM/yy`* No, it was referencing the "30/11/12".  If you use `DateTime.Parse()` or `TryParse` - they will try to use *all* the date time formats registered for a culture.  *Your* format setting ought not matter using `InvariantCulture`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has something to do with Culture,  ist seems to be the dateformat u r passing : "dd/MM/yy"

Try this :

DateTime.ParseExact("30/11/12","d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Wouldn't this only return the day?

Comment: This code will throw an exception as "30/11/12" is not a date in the form "d" (day of month).